# TreeView Bold Node (C#)

Tags: c#, treeview

I just have a quick question, actually, I just want to know if it’s possible to check if a node from a treeview is in Bold?
Because I can’t find a solution on the Internet.

I have try this in my code :

```
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodesTvMsg)
            {

                if (node.NodeFont.Bold == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("BOLD");
                } 
}
```

but it also works for those who are not bold and I also have this mistake :
The object reference is not defined to an instance of an object.

Thank in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didnt assign New Font object which has Bold prop. not set true it is seen as false, you can diagnose easly "node.NodeFont.Bold == false"   making true as false  if it works. It means bold is set as false.